# ngx-translate special chars getting capitalize

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular6

For special accents in language during translation gets capitalized as below:

[image]

I have used like this in HTML:

```
{{ 'WORD' | translate | titlecase }}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did is created custom pipe for this named **customTitle** as below:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
 name: 'customTitle',
})
export class CustomTitlePipe implements PipeTransform {
 transform(input: string): string {
  return input.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.slice(1).toLocaleLowerCase();
 }
}
```

The accents do not get capitalized as in case with inbuilt titlecase pipe.